# How to limit get access to only a few folders within the same parent folder using htaccess?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, unix

I currently have the following folder structure.

```
/downloads/
    —/contracts/
    —/user_images/
    —/passports/
    —/applications/
    .htaccess
```

What I would like to achieve is to restrict GET LIMIT on the `contracts` and `passports` folders while `user_images` and `applications` folders are fully accessible.

**.htaccess**

```
<Limit GET>
    order allow, deny
    deny from all
</Limit>
```

My `.htaccess` file is restricting all access with the `downloads` folder. Can anyone advise how I can access only the `user_images` and `applications`folders and its content while the rest of the folders are restricted?

Comment: You can not use `Directory` or `Location` directives in .htaccess, and I don’t know if wrapping `FilesMatch` around this with an expression trying to target the path, would work. The easiest way would really be if you just put an .htaccess file directly into both of these sub folders each.